# laravel-websockets connect to channles without laravel-echo

Tags: laravel, websocket, socket.io, laravel-echo, laravel-websockets

I have a websocket server implemented with [laravel-websockets](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction)  package which broadcasts data on some private channels. At the moment server does not support two-way communication. I want to make this public for anyone to be able to connect to this websocket by using an auth token. But I can't find anything helpful regarding this.

Currently I am using laravel-echo and pusher-js to connect from a separate app which works fine. But what if someone does not want to use these packages i.e. what would be the nodejs implementation to connect to this socket.

For reference here is my `laravel-echo` implementation to connect to this socket.

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '{appkey}',
    wsHost: '{sockethosturl}',
    wsPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: false,
    authEndpoint: '{auth endpoint on socket server}',
    disableStats: true,
    auth: {
        headers: {
            'Auth-Token': '{ random auth token }',
        }
    }
});
```

And then I subscribe to channels using this

```
Echo.private('private-channel-1')
    .listen('.update', (event) => {
         console.log("Found event");
         console.log(event);
     });
```

Looking for a way to translate this into a `socket-io` or any other websocket client side library.